# Install Win7 on MacBook Pro with USB Drive

Tags: windows-7, macos, iso-image

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro, and I want to install Win7 on it. I have a Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate (64 Bit) iso file and an 8GB USB Flash drive.
I've tried several ways of putting in the ISO file on the Flash drive, but I always end up with the drive formatted as UDF, which seems to be not bootable from my mac. I've seen that Microsoft has a tool to put the iso on an USB drive "Windows USB/DVD Download Tool" but I have no Windows machine to run that from. Could anyone help me with a workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If MacOS is still there, why don't you try to install Win7 using Bootcamp?
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016

Would like to put this in a comment but SU is still reconciling my profiles so as of now I've only 11 reputation points :(

Comment: Because I'm truly dumb, apparently :) . I did read the instructions, and thought I've done it thoroughly, but I did not read the crucial "An authentic Microsoft Windows full install disc *or ISO* file of Windows 7 64-bit, Windows 7 32-bit, Windows XP, or Windows Vista." I will try it now and report back.

Comment: Bootcamp does not recognise the (mounted or unmounted) ISO file as the Windows installation disc. So I'm stuck again

Comment: @Fede What about etching the ISO on a DVD and usa that instead of an usb drive?

Comment: Thanks microspino. Unfortunately it was a dead end, BootCampAssistant was never able to produce a bootable USB drive, I tried a lot of different ways, granted I did not try yours, only because I'm not able to get a DVD-R where I live within the time frame I had. In any case I ended up migrating an old installation of Bootcamp with Win7 from an old drive I had lying around using WinClone. As for the reasons why it did not work, I found some reports online that said that the actual "drive" could be the issue, as some brands would work, and some other would not, anything is possible.... Thanks!